# Is it possible to play the Tower of Hanoi with fewer than $2^n-1$ moves?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The Tower of Hanoi game consists of three identical upright pegs and n rings all of different diameters that can be stacked over any of the pegs. Initially, all of the rings are stacked around one of the pegs in order of decreasing diameter with the largest ring on the bottom. The object of the game is to transfer all the rings, one at a time, until they are stacked in the same order around another peg, but at no time may any ring be placed above a ring of smaller diameter.

Prove that, for any number of rings, the transfer can be made in exactly $2^n-1$ moves.

We need to use induction...

Basis Step

IF we let $n=1$, then the left hand side must be 1 and the right hand side must be one as well.

$1 = 2^1-1$

$1 = 1$

Induction Step.

If $P(k)$ is true, then we can move $k$ disks in $2^k-1$ moves.

If $P(k+1)$ is true, then we can move $k+1$ disks $2^{k+1}-1$

Let $2^k - 1 $ be the number of moves for $k$ disks. Then,

$2(2^k-1)+1$

Using our induction hypothesis, we have

$2(2^{k+1}-1)$.

For any $ k \geq 1$, $P(k)$ and $P(k+1)$ is true.

Edit: This isn't right at all... it's just fluff...I need to start over.

Can the Tower of Hanoi be played in less than $2^n-1$ steps?

This is where I'm stuck... My guess is that unless you break the rules of the game, then you can't play  in fewer steps. Do I use induction to prove that it's impossible or possible?

Comment: You need to use the rules to do the induction. You did not show that $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$.

Comment: Alright so....where did I not show the $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$?

Comment: To use the induction hypothesis, you start with $k+1$ disks, show how to reduce to $k$ disks and at that point use the inductive hypothesis. You can't just state the result that you want and then use it.

Comment: Your title says "$2^n-1$ fewer moves." $2^n-1$ fewer than what? Or do you mean "fewer than $2^n-1$ moves." That seems more likely.

Comment: Can you help me step by step? I know some parts of the induction hypothesis and then I get stuck because there's one line that I don't understand.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews will edit thanks ...

Comment: "Where did I not show..." is a bit confusing. Everywhere is where you did not show it.

Comment: alright let's start this over... I know that we need to prove the basis and the induction steps... for induction

Comment: so the basis step is really easy to do ... 

$2^n - 1 $ 

so if I let $n = 1 $, then $2^1 - 1$ so that 's one.

Answer (score 2):

Actrually it is impossible to do this, it really need $2^{n}-1$ moves.

We can prove it in the following way:

Let $a_{n}$ be the number of moves to finish a Hanoi with $n$ disks. Now we prove that $a_{n}=2^{n}-1$.

1. For $n=1$, we just need one move, so $a_{1}=1=2^{1}-1$, equation holds when $n=1$.
2. We suppose equation holds when $n=k$, that is to say $a_{k}=2^{k}-1$.

   For $n=k+1$,

   a) We first need to move the top $k$ disks from pile A to B by using pile C, it costs $2^{k}-1$ moves.

   b) Then we need to move the last disk from pile A to C, which just costs one move.

   c) At last, we need to move all the $k$ disks from pile B to C by using pile A, it costs another $2^{k}-1$ moves.

   Now, we have already finish the game when $n=k+1$.

   Let calculate $a_{k+1}$, it will be like this by adding all the moves above

   $$a_{k+1}=a_{k}+1+a_{k}=2a_{k}+1=2\left(2^{k}-1\right)+1=2^{k+1}-1.$$

   Equation holds when $n=k+1$.

From 1. and 2. we can arrive the conclusion that $a_{n}=2^{n}-1$.

So it is impossible to finish a Hanoi game by using less than $2^{n}-1$ moves.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get this started. We want to show that for $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 1$ that $P(n) = 2^n-1$ is the number of moves required to complete the Tower of Hanoi.

Base case: $n=1$

There is only $1$ disc so it only takes $1$ move to get it from the first peg to the last peg and $2^1-1=1$ so $P(1)$ is true.

Inductive hypothesis: Assume for some $k \geq 1$ that $P(k)=2^k-1$ is true. We want to show that $P(k+1)=2^{k+1}-1$ is true.

Start with an initial stack of $k+1$ discs. At this point you need to use the rules of the game to get to a stack with $k$ discs so you can use the inductive hypothesis.

---

I'm going to let you try to fill in the details at this point. But let's take a look at what happens when $n=2$. With 2 discs on the first peg, we move the top disc to the second peg. Then we move the bottom disc to the third peg. Then we move the top disc from the middle peg to the third peg. This takes $2*(1)+1 = 3$ moves. Note that the $(1)$ represents the times we move the top disc.

Comment: Here are the rules: 

The objective of the puzzle is to move the entire stack to another rod, obeying the following simple rules:

    Only one disk can be moved at a time.
    Each move consists of taking the upper disk from one of the stacks and placing it on top of another stack i.e. a disk can only be moved if it is the uppermost disk on a stack.
    No disk may be placed on top of a smaller disk.

so we need to information to get $k$ discs and $k+1$ discs

Comment: @usukidoll I know the rules. I've done this proof before. It seems to be a favorite when students are learning induction.

Comment: So suppose have $n = k$... there are $k$ disks and that would be 
$P(k) = 2^k-1$ right?

Comment: and then we have $n=k+1$ which means that there are $k+1$ disks... $P(k+1) = 2^{k+1}-1$

Comment: You have to show that $P(k+1)=2^{k+1}-1$. You can not use that fact anywhere in your proof.

Comment: so we need to get to the result of $P(k+1) = 2^{k+1} - 1$... with what though? use $P(k)= 2^k -1$ as a starting point?

Comment: Right. You start with $k+1$ discs and find a way to work with just $k$ of them. Then you can use the result because we know it is true for $k$.

Comment: How though? There's one part of induction that doesn't make sense.. like do I multiply both sides? add both sides?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12895/discussion-between-john-habert-and-usukidoll)