# Hanoi Towers, the k-th move

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to find the k-th move in an Hanoi Towers instance with n discs: a. why there is need of $2^n-1 $steps? b. why $k=2^{n-1}$ is the move of the disk n from start to the target? (if there are three bars start, via and the last is target)

Comment: this is related to my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666989/is-it-possible-to-play-the-tower-of-hanoi-with-fewer-than-2n-1-moves

Answer (score 0):

a.  You can't move disk $n$ until you have moved all the other $n-1$ disks to the same target
b.  You prove this by recursion.  Try it by hand for 1,2,3 disks and you might see a pattern.